# Software developers with $2$ years experience

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

Statistics suggest that software developer with 2 years of experience in a town earn an average of **70,000** per year, with a standard deviation of **5,000**. To verify this salary level, a random sample of **100** software developers with 2 years of experience was selected from a personnel database for all software developers in the town.

a) Describe the sampling distribution of the sample mean of the average salary of these **100** software developers.

b) Calculate the probability that the sample mean is greater than or equal to **71,200**.

c) If the random sample actually produced a sample mean of **71,200**, would you consider this rather unusual? What conclusion might you draw then?

My work:

a) the sampling distribution of the sample mean follows a normal distribution since **n>30**.

b) **z = (71,200 - μ)/[σ / sqrt(n)] = 2.4**, I then used this value for z in order to find the probability: **P(x ≥ 71,200) = P(z ≥ 2.4) = 0.0082**

c) I would consider this unusual since the probability that the sample mean is greater than or equal to 71,200 is **0.82%**. I'm not too sure about the "What conclusion should you draw then" part..

I'm not sure if I am solving this correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

In part b) you should divide $\sigma$ by $\sqrt n$, dont subtract it from $\sigma$.so, you need to recompute z-statistics and your conclusion on part c will depend on the new z-statistics.

Comment: That typo went completely unnoticed to me! Thank you for pointing that out!